# Angular ng-valid-email "blocked" with intervening custom directive

Tags: angularjs, validation, input

I am implementing a custom directive in Angular 1.4 which creates a inner input element within a form.  I am having problems with the validation.

1)  When make the email invalid (add a '.' to the end of the string in the input box), the ng-invalid-email class does not get propagated upwards to the form (possibly because the vc-input directive is in the way?).  So it is reporting it as "required invalid" as opposed to "email invalid".

2)  If I change vc-input to just input (and remove closing vc-input element), it works as expected (try in snippet).

Is there some way I can make sure this validity passes through the way it's supposed to?

```js
'use strict';

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp
  .directive('vcInput', ['$compile',
    function ($compile) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',

        link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
          var toDash = function(str){
            return str.replace(/([A-Z])/g, function($1){return '-'+$1.toLowerCase();});
          };

          // returned glyph string could be glyphicon or fontawesome
          var mapIcon = function(iconName) {
            var glyphName = '';

            if (iconName === 'search') {
              glyphName = 'glyphicon glyphicon-search';
            }
            else if (iconName === 'user') {
              glyphName = 'glyphicon glyphicon-user';
            }
            else if (iconName === 'password') {
              glyphName = 'glyphicon glyphicon-lock';
            }
            else if (iconName === 'token') {
              glyphName = 'glyphicon glyphicon-tags';
              glyphName = 'fa fa-tags';
            }

            return glyphName;
          };

          var leadIcon = elem.attr('lead-icon');
          elem.removeAttr('lead-icon');

          var leadClass;
          var spanClass = '';

          if (leadIcon !== undefined) {
            leadClass = mapIcon(leadIcon);
            if (leadClass) {
              spanClass = 'left-inner-addon';
            }
            else {
              spanClass = 'left-inner-no-icon';
            }
          }

          var icon = '';
          if (leadClass !== undefined) {
            icon = '<i class="' + leadClass + '"></i>';
          }

          var elementData = elem[0].outerHTML;
          var startIndex = elementData.indexOf('<vc-input') + 9;
          var stopIndex = elementData.indexOf('>') ;
          var allAtt = elementData.substring(startIndex, stopIndex);

          angular.forEach(attrs, function(value, key) {
            if (key.lastIndexOf('$',0) && key !== 'leadIcon') {
              elem.removeAttr(toDash(key));
            }
          });

          var span1 = '<span class="' + spanClass + '">';
          var span2 = '</span>';
          var html = $compile(span1 + icon + '<input ' + allAtt + '/>' + span2)($scope);
          elem.html(html);
          
        }

      };
    }])


;
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
<form name="myForm">
    <label>Email:
        <vc-input type="email" name="input" ng-model="email.text" ng-init="email.text='joe@aol.com'" required></vc-input>
    </label>
    <div role="alert">
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.required">
        Required!</span>
      <span class="error" ng-show="myForm.input.$error.email">
        Not valid email!</span>
    </div>
    <samp>text = {{email.text}}</samp><br/>
    <samp>myForm.input.$valid = {{myForm.input.$valid}}</samp><br/>
    <samp>myForm.input.$error = {{myForm.input.$error}}</samp><br/>
    <samp>myForm.$valid = {{myForm.$valid}}</samp><br/>
    <samp>myForm.$error.required = {{!!myForm.$error.required}}</samp><br/>
    <samp>myForm.$error.email = {{!!myForm.$error.email}}</samp><br/>
</form>
</div>
```